# Why doesn't g++ fully optimize these loops / operator calls?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, g++, inlining

Consider this `struct` which can for example represent a structure of 2 4D vectors:

```
struct A {
    double x[4];
    double y[4];

    A() : A(0.0, 0.0) { }
    A(double xp, double yp)
    {
        std::fill_n(x, 4, xp);
        std::fill_n(y, 4, yp);
    }

    // Simple element-wise delegation of the mathematical operations
    friend A operator+(const A &l, const A &r) 
    {
        A res;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            res.x[i] = l.x[i] + r.x[i];
            res.y[i] = l.y[i] + r.y[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    friend A operator*(const A &l, const double &r) 
    {
        A res;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            res.x[i] = l.x[i] * r;
            res.y[i] = l.y[i] * r;
        }
        return res;
    }
    friend A operator*(const double &l, const A &r) 
    {
        A res;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            res.x[i] = l * r.x[i];
            res.y[i] = l * r.y[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const A &a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            std::cout << "(" << a.x[i] << "|" << a.y[i] << ") ";
        return stream;
    }
};
```

For convenience, the `struct` has a few operators defined, which simply delegate to member- and element-wise operations.

Now, consider two different versions of a second `struct B`, that contains objects of `A`:

```
struct B { // version 1
    double f1; 
    double f2; // Two coefficients
    A buff1;
    A buff2;
    A buffa[4]; // Objects of struct A
    // The following functions use the operators defined on struct A
    void mathA(int i, double d) // Some math operations
    {
        buff2 = buff1 + buffa[i] * d;
    }
    void mathB() // Some more math (vector) operations
    {
        buff1 = f1 * (buffa[0] + buffa[3]) + f2 * (buffa[1] + buffa[2]);
    }
};
```

and

```
struct B { // version 2
    double f1; 
    double f2; // Two coefficients
    A buff1;
    A buff2;
    A buffa[4]; // Objects of struct A
    // The following functions DO NOT use the operators defined on struct A
    void mathA(int i, double d) // Some math operations
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            buff2.x[j] = buff1.x[j] + buffa[i].x[j] * d;
            buff2.y[j] = buff1.y[j] + buffa[i].y[j] * d;
        }
    }
    void mathB() // Some more math (vector) operations
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            buff1.x[j] = f1 * (buffa[0].x[j] + buffa[3].x[j]) + f2 * (buffa[1].x[j] + buffa[2].x[j]);
            buff1.y[j] = f1 * (buffa[0].y[j] + buffa[3].y[j]) + f2 * (buffa[1].y[j] + buffa[2].y[j]);
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, the secont version of `struct B` performs the same mathematical operations, but the first version uses the operators of `struct A` while the second performs these operations manually in `mathA` and `mathB`. Note that the second version of `struct B` does not actually use the operators defined in `struct A`.

Let's add a main function to test the functionality of `struct B` (Diff window, "Left"):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    B b;
    b.f1 = 0.5;
    b.f2 = 0.8;
    b.buff1 = A(0.7, 0.8);
    b.buff2 = A(1.7, 2.8);

    b.mathA(1, 0.9);
    b.mathB();

    std::cout << b.buff1 << "\n" << b.buff2;
}
```

I have prepared examples of both cases in godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwnlSCCxTEwC2G7BwAMAQQuW9xEcgKrL6gOx8rqr6vSiARgyYqgAeHACsPAAs4QAiGh4u3r4iAUEAnuFRsfE2Nt7OEACUqiAF5gB05qSqFebFHO5ucZ7elhDJqSEADtUdgappXYV53g0J%2Bfl66CAgAGZ4DAwA%2BiwQwdWR1cFDOS0TqlMz84srEGkb1YPDsuOjrs3We6oA9M%2BqAMp4Rl39mIFGmBYBAAtAB3PCCIJYQLAJgEHQsVSoWaqAgIIJGOHozHw5BMBhIrqYYhwhGCEZeWbEPCA9DOQnEuEkfgQNAsPT07gANgY1TZHJc3OI9SeYwpExcBnJN3F%2BVmJFUEAUTjw6lkMRq8VUqo0mlU0Ru2v4/GGT3yYrN%2B1UUvKoQieFiao1DFtmQdYQ1/Gtrvt2Rllv2Noyvo9TtULuDPHdnt43sj0d2iX2DQeVutmAIYkRUsT5vu4qpNJYdJcqCJJKIxGBrNQ7Kcgq4PL5tYF6kbwvFFqTEvT0tu%2B3lxEVyu1YfMWp1Wn1E%2BNvFN3bz/bTvZ9UcdGmdq%2BjqmB3rta49ueXXiDbvX6vD5Xjjt3xCvZ8P/oXd1TVoMmeI2cwfc7%2BaeDa5MtGUrY11RrOtOXbedF1lbxB2HIFRw3TVDUnPUDR4I1eBNWCvC7Y8vH3bdQI1O8iL9Jc02vUMSLjB84ifNMU1w9MP0RAAqNEISPPC/27QtaXpICKxIdjwNbbleVUfknD6IIhRFbt8KtSVvx4iZ4KVRDJw1cdULVdCZ2wucWOU48bXImiLxdSyNXY611LTU8Q09az7xc1R7OIRyXxY98s17dTmKeATiyE8smWIMSZJ8fx%2Bkk5sIIA4V1FFdwWNUn8A1UTSRx0lDMLQ6dUNnHhoKtMzlws%2BiwwJLytwolj8mcg9XOdTy6JcnzeNfQMMwCnNGN8kLqUEw4QF0fRDCMNtAIikCtF1CBxsmgxjFmuxpsSiTGyYcreMouCFS0lUxwnAzisK0r9uXca0BEJxdV1NsuAgbguAM56mAaqzNGe96Gj%2BrgPqeqdvuo1y/qnd76mB7rWICzbjCCvjmKfGw7AcJxMLGF43gAN2JQQEVUWhxTknKycNcm4qCWYuC1V5VAAFVBVBpNQTBZnmZAiwIcl/1UPwRG5qmlxcYXuYZoavAlkXZiYTJokfTCmYAeT8KhMEcQQkRRTHHGccUmeZ9EctQRZUHBNgcpERR4RbVQREhVEzeEyLdaweYWEwOlawOfQsaNp58dQPA6RxBA2jy3paZ8YomfeVAAVUSOGQrMlf0OrxJfpsNc9oNtMNzxWPPs9AUd61RQ/D1OsR4Io8Y%2BZOMRIDEsUVQnHBIYp3Yd9ks5Yguw1mQv7IgEvMnHGjY0niJZFiWHMLz8e554MmZ%2BL%2BXS54BmPWuJdgusfN0asEdMQUE7VCYYhgGQPkEBvzz2Jv4B8fnSri/UvxylHsdyjCN/X%2BIMLwVAABxAOHshNoFRXDVHAQfcUP9c4gI1G0Wg5Q4GqC4OUMBiCrBIPKJHdB8DygAE58Hdh/pHBulDxR3VEI9RaU5kHy0LqDPUAMwiaBYO9T6LDygoMTEfGwUhCiMGkGEKQpAWDSHMNI1A0ggZ8FjMIMQEg2yyFoNIggcixHiIANYgC4BUMIrgyFhC4GELk5hIiuDAbIMhXIJFSEiNI2RUh5GkEUVIaRggQBVF0Z4sRpA4CwCQGgLAuBCAkHIJQGgXBGCsHYKVIQohxCSBkFweQihlBqF1DoJGJhZBmAIVYA29Y3BLgpvuZWDFqlx0jHU4R/5G6lBgZUUhdQqlNHFG0GpPRYopH6FcQe2VxrHGWKsdY%2Botg7BlhMCZCwplnAuAMeZh9UZPETl8H4QQ/iYABECMEEIoQHNhP3PWrt25okOaSPEBI%2B6ZxGkWEs6dIoshigBKSXzZopTGc%2BWWgUFlymOnlM6%2BlnoYSwiosqpl0rZWat%2BH6bVLy2SLnuei8MkWCHcq1WqeLiKxjvBDeGR8nL9U/MCzZVdQpvL7iQasvyEocySn8m6lV8iZXhrlbSELCoXWhQ6YycLsqcrfMi9FyEbI1VvCi7F3gWrETchDHcnVWpkr4hSti1LfxVwAgy7y2EwLMqggCtMvLTrIT0gKqFRlYU3Rgoi7wUrjWkXlSCq0qraIkqxZ6nqflKUcS4llJSWq4KjTCqWeaolxKVJZTFCmClUphuzvSQaabLVIVAedO1JURWOruGmnFKKCXoq8gqk8yLvUqpqhW/1vTsr%2BSpRmvVBZI30pjVFONQzOgJpbPGqCKanWAvTWpBtWb8o2uzYZfNDr4XFsVZKmq0qOpkT9YuqtuKa3tXqqSht5KJU6tbWlWlHaA7TAmkU2ahqOHLQIJe1a00NpTWMNtQdXI9rmqtJO/lM7Lowpws6rwDCHr8M4cDN6wNwPX1LRwl6gM%2BHwfBiu5hEGuCw2lmm5tiIimV1yCfBIGNA6Gxxo0JmhNiDE39gzJ4FNR5ahpsMumWGm6s3ZmgLmPM%2BYC27HLUW6l%2BP00E0LbeSsKJNw1lrHWVyKnB27CbM28pLbW2ALbe2ZJVAxDVqoAAcmrZmTsXa3PeZWT2XMFC%2ByRLhkj9ZxQ1wjliaO2lY7Mfjk3JOKc05PJbN%2BgcYLEJUD/UFvNmEqDXQXU1bwKDVzhashqAusX1yzzEy5JLoZy6VtE1LPFcXUWJcjHljFa9oy5cdJlg94aA0hzDo5tEtCPMt1Tm3OuaJO7a0rL3eazzU0sSzSFnNhoBuzrCxFsVCLR35ES/uIryE/6r1SzwaeMR0sxi3tzHeC8PSraXjlD6C2NuZA3itmbyX1sK0yHvE7mQ8uUIItl0eZX4uUw6hPRby2ntrYe5t2In3dsr0VGvY7n3iuLau39zVVcRGEdyGfRCF9VgjlfvfaSj8hzsRfrfd%2BBGlxfwWT/P%2B1qAFALzkTiB%2BPBFsLDB0rBCDIHy1QQUDBWCcF4JaVQohTmID0BqOQu70XOf1aKOzyYD6Zj3SYVDPUrDRYwa4TwpDaGhaU6lsIrZlgQkMEke4vR3ilGlQOOkjRcguA6L0YUQxxiMGyFcK4RxYCHc29kGEWgXJNha9cTr4JevfFCACaQIJ8jxFhMQCAfA3M4kQAYAgfx9BiAx%2BMeIj3UiZG658TEPA3MQhgK5MCN3qg77IFUK4cohd8a62CDnvPkQC/ICLyX7RAfzeW8iLIcokQyFcDIbQcwDue/mB71yZxHu3Gp%2B9z4vx/vA8hJD7PiJycugLGJJHtA3wl/EBAMAVw9BjgECJpQPwuu/AKBvmkaQjfV9HIIGrFgDAz/e6wJiNggRdf4AMI4PAhN/He8wMEbWD1MlG9lQ/hdcGA8A/ASRiA0hNAMBACdFqQjBz9NdkkUBUkwC/B/FIBxEyx%2B5v9gQ1ZZA/EjdJBaAk9tcx8vEfFK9c989C9i9S9FRolKxNEecYC19Aghw5BSDVBlF%2BAzdgkLdSB0QmAsAN8igXFR9ECzFKhzBZArE7cuAwEyEyFzBskKCFFpBJ9AlzdQkYBQ9V9F8OCV8F919N9t9SBd998J4j8T8oCkDSBL9ARr9b978vFH9kkX8H88B394Qv9ddf9/8997DgCPcvF0DIDoDYD7D9AvgkCk8UDOARVGBwDMDxCcCyRpB8DCC0l1FJAMMXEU8PFKDpBqDq9a968GCIAmCFQTdqg2DDDiRNEMMeDSp%2BCg9xFhDRDKBLdgZyFXBIhaAzEuQuBaBIhFDaA4ER9pFECxjyEnF%2BjGxt9zBzAyFbd1CfctCm8BDLdRiAEwgB83cuRZBbFzEwErEXFsiiiNDfdp9BCPdTd1iJ8tj2jSBKNqNZFIggA%3D%3D). Both cases are compiled using g++ 7.1.0 on optimization level `-O3`. The left case corresponds to version 1, the right case to version 2 of `struct B`.

As you can see in the disassembly, the compiler generates two labels for version 1, which correspond to the `mathX` functions in `struct B`:

> `64     B::mathA(int, double):` 
>   […] 
>   `76     B::mathB():`

As my analysis shows, the first example is much slower compared to the second example. The functions are called more than 1 billion times in my actual code and are thus very much contributing to the overall runtime. I assume this is partially due to the jumps to the function definitions.

Is there a way to force the compiler to produce an assembly that is identical to the second example? I.e. with using the definitions of the operators?

### Update

Since the compiler seemed to generate labels and jumps for `mathX(…)` my idea was to attempt to inline these functions. Using the `inline` keyword changed nothing, but for g++ you can use `__attribute__((always_inline))` which will force the compiler to inline the function ([documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html)):

```
struct B { // version 3
    // …
    mathA(int i, double d) __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        // …
    }
    mathB() __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        // …
    }
};
```

This improved the performance, which is now somewhere between version 1 and version 2. This is still not perfect, but if no better solution will be found, I will go with this one.

Comment: I tried both version 1 and 2 on -O2, and clang appears to produce the exact same assembly, and also inline it. https://godbolt.org/z/nOwGg8